# Is it possible to use a video for image-based lighting?

Tags: video, lighting, hdri

When I discovered the use of HDRI to light a scene in Blender, I was blown away by the difference it made to my scenes.
What I'd like to know is whether it is possible to use a video to light a scene in the same way.
For example, if I had footage of a sunrise, could I use it to light my own scenes?  I realise that the video would not have the same dynamic range, but it's the combination of light levels and colour that I would like to use to light a scene of a forest clearing.  It's for an animated, projected backdrop for a theatrical play so the resulting video doesn't have to be be that photo-realistic.

I can't find anything in the Blender manual that would suggest it's possible, so I'm hoping somebody has found a way.  Otherwise I'm going to have to come up with some way of making a realistic sunrise.

Comment: BTW the environment texture node also supports videos. So in case you have a 360° video recorded (or rendered), you could use this to light the scene.

Comment: Ah, that's useful to know, gtzkw.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a plane and give a material that has a emission shader and the color is plugged in to a image sequence.

Note: you might have to set the fourth drop down menu to movie, and make sure that you the the frames property on the image sequence.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  
I just discovered that you could import a movie into Blender and create an image sequence from it.  Basically it's the way Blender objects are inserted into real footage (VFX).  So all I need to do is import my video, and add my scene objects in front of it and render the result.

Comment: It will only work if your imagery is scene referred or your footage is log encoded.

Comment: Note that this *works in Cycles only*. (From my experience, Eevee will ignore such an emission setup as light.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got this to work in EEVEE as well by clicking on the *World Properties* tab, selecting the *Viewport Display* area, and clicking the dot to the right of the *Color* bar.